# Serialize to json nested one-to-many (opposite of many to one)

Tags: django, django-models

I have Installs which have many Modules which each have many Versions.

a-la:

```
class Module(Models.Model):
    install = models.ForeignKey(Install)
```

One Install has many Modules.

I want to serialize this whole set to a json structure.

I found that I can use the [wad of stuff serializer](https://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/wiki/DjangoFullSerializers#Relations) to serialize in this way:

```
 serializers.serialize("json", Version.objects.all(), indent=4, 
                        relations={'module':{'relations':('install',)}})
```

But this is starting from the inside out (a many-to-one view - many versions have one module, but I want to know what versions each module has).   I get  list of Versions at the top level, with each Version calling out it's Module, so the each Module is listed many times:

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1, 
        "model": "cmh_server.version", 
        "fields": {
            "name": "v1", 
            "module": {
                "pk": 1, 
                "model": "cmh_server.module", 
                "fields": {
                    "install": {
                        "pk": 1, 
                        "model": "cmh_server.install", 
                        "fields": {
                            "name": "CMBN"
                        }
                    }, 
                    "name": "CMBN", 
                }
            }
        },
        "pk": 2, 
        "model": "cmh_server.version", 
        "fields": {
            "name": "v1.1", 
            "module": {
                "pk": 1, 
                "model": "cmh_server.module", 
                "fields": {
                    "install": {
                        "pk": 1, 
                        "model": "cmh_server.install", 
                        "fields": {
                            "name": "CMBN"
                        }
                    }, 
                    "name": "CMBN", 
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

See how the same Module is listed twice.   That's "not right".

I want to say something like

```
serializers.serialize("json", Install.objects.all(), indent=4, 
                      relations={'module':{'relations':('version',)}})
```

but of course that doesn't work because the Install model does not have a field called "module".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using django rest framework.

Define a model serializer for Module model and Version model:

```
class VersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Version

class ModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    versions = VersionSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Module
        fields = ('id', ..... , 'versions')
```

Now define your Install model serialiser:

```
class InstallSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    modules = ModuleSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Install
        fields = ('id', ..... , 'modules')
```

This will serialize install data with all modules for each install and also all versions for each of the modules in a install.

EDIT:

I forgot to mention this, the name of the field of the related model should be the same as the value of related_name in the foreign key field.

For example in the Module model:

```
class Module(Models.Model):
    install = models.ForeignKey(Install, related_name='modules')
```

Now you have to use 'modules' as the name of the field in the serializer.

Comment: That looks quite attractive.   The main drawback appears to be that these seralizer classes have to be modified if the class itself is modified, right?  I mean - the fields list will have to be manually updated?

Comment: To include a field in a model serializer which is not a actual field in the model you need to explicitly define the fields attribute in the Meta class. To avoid listing down the actual fields of the model serializer you can use Model._meta.fields to generate a list of names of model fields. This way you don't have to worry about updating the fields attribute manually.

Comment: I guess the model in the InstallSerializer should be Install?    When I try `i = Install.objects.get(pk=1); InstalLSerializer(i).data`  I get "AttributeError: 'Install' object has no attribute 'modules'
"

Comment: Yes, that is right. Thanks for the correction. Also I have edited my answer, please rename the field names in the serializers.

Comment: Suhweeeet! :)  Thanks!

Comment: Hey - where can I read more about this?  I looked at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers, but it doesn't have this related_name magic....

Comment: You can read this page http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#further-notes , DRF has awesome documentation.